# Compare values of 2 string arrays in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I have 2 arrays:

```
all_fruits = ["Orange", "Apple", "Banana"]
selected_fruits = ["Orange",  "Banana"]
```

And i would like to do something like:

```
 {{#each all_fruits}}
   {{#each selected_fruits}}

// if all_fruits == selected_fruits
// do something

   {{/each}}
 {{/each}}
```

But I do not know how to iterate both of them at the same time to know which values in *all_fruits* also exist in *selected_fruits*

Comment: I think you need to be explicit about what kind of equality you are looking for. Do you really want to know if `all_fruits` _equals_ `selected_fruits`, ie., both variables reference the same Array Object? Or do you want to do a "deep equal" comparison of the two Arrays, ie., check that for every `i`, `all_fruits[i]` equals `selected_fruits[i]`? Or do you just want to know which values in `all_fruits` _also exist_ in `selected_fruits`?

Comment: oh yes, my mistake, sorry

Comment: I wouldn't `#each` over `all_fuits`. I would just write a helper that takes a value and an Array and returns `true` if the value is in the Array, or else `false`. Then I would use this helper for each values in `selected_fruits` against the `all_fruits` Array.